# Data Column Expression check null

Tags: c#, datatable, expression

I have some code like this:

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable(); // New data table.
        table.Columns.Add("ClientId", typeof(int));
        table.Rows.Add(1);
        table.Rows.Add(2);
        table.Rows.Add(3);
        table.Rows.Add(4);
        table.Rows.Add(DBNull.Value);
        table.Rows.Add(DBNull.Value);

        table.Columns.Add("Section", typeof(string), "IIF(ClientId=Null,'Generic','Client')");
```

Right now, ever row is being give the value of client, in essence the ClientId=Null is always returning false.

What am I doing wrong here?

I want it so that if the row value of ClientId is null then the Section value will be genereic, otherwise the Section value will be Client.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Change ClientId=Null to ClientId is Null, if that is VBA then maybe ClientId is nothing probably works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your Expression to

```
 table.Columns.Add("Section", typeof(string), 
                    "IIF((ISNULL(ClientId,0)=0),'Generic','Client')");
```

Well, of course no value zero should be present in the ClientId column, otherwise choose another value guaranteed to not exists in the values (like -1)

Explanation

```
ISNULL(expression, replacement_value)
```

In case of NULL the return of ISNULL is the replacement value, then this value is compared with the fixed constant zero to produce the boolean result required by the IIF expression. If the comparison between the result of ISNULL and zero is true then the first string is selected as value for the Section column